# ScreenshotClient update() call results in memory leak

Tags: android, screen-capture, surfaceflinger

I am working on a Jetson TK1 board. I have modified the code for screencap application to read the contents of the screen in a while loop and save the data as images.
For this, I use the update() method from the ScreenshotClient class. After running 100 iterations of the while loop, I noticed that the heap size of my process keeps on increasing. I do call the release() method before every update() call. My code looks as shown below.

```
while(count < 100)
{
    screenshot->release();
    screenshot->update(display, Rect(0, 0), false);
    count++;
}
```

I am not sure about what could be the reason for this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have this line in your initialization:

```
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>
...
android::ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
```